# Javascript: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {"

Tags: javascript

I'm writing my first *javascript* code and when I try to run it, I get the following error

> "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {"

Why is this happening in this case?

```
var red = [0, 100, 63];
var orange = [40, 100, 60];
var green = [75, 100, 40];
var blue = [196, 77, 55];
var purple = [280, 50, 60];

var myName = "Manuel";
letterColors = [red, orange, green]
If (15 > 5 ){
bubbleShape = "circle"
}
else{
    bubbleShape = "square"
}

drawName(myName, letterColors);
```

Answer (score 3):

`If` should be `if`.  Remember, Javascript is case-sensitive, and all JS keywords are lower-case.

As an aside...

You are missing a semicolon on several lines, but, as Brad pointed out in the comments, Javascript does not always require semicolons at the end of statements, unless you need to delimit two adjacent statments.  In this particular case, the absense of these semicolons isn't causing any errors.  That said, it's best to get in the habit of including even non-essential semicolons at the end of your statements to avoid accidentally introducing syntax errors later.

Comment: JavaScript doesn't require a semicolon on the previous line.

Comment: True, but it's good practice.  That semicolon isn't what is causing your error, but in general it's best to include non-essential semicolons.  Thanks for the clarification @Brad

Comment: I completely agree, use semicolons... it adds clarity.  It's just important to be very accurate in answers, especially to folks new to the language.

Comment: Would be good to mention that he doesn't need that `if` at all... 15 will always be greather than 5.

Answer (score 1):

```
If (15 > 5 ){ //<<< should be if as javascript is case-sensitive
bubbleShape = "circle"
}
else{
    bubbleShape = "square"
}
```

**Working:**

```
var red = [0, 100, 63];
var orange = [40, 100, 60];
var green = [75, 100, 40];
var blue = [196, 77, 55];
var purple = [280, 50, 60];

var myName = "Manuel";
letterColors = [red, orange, green];
if (15 > 5 ){
bubbleShape = "circle";
}
else{
    bubbleShape = "square";
}

drawName(myName, letterColors);
```

I wouldn't set bubbleShape as a global but pass it as a variable to the function like you do it with your other vars.