# javascript Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token { error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have my javascript code(Below).I am getting error :  `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token { error`
But I am unable to find any problem in my code. Can anyone help me?

This is a web service string which returns inside the code and I am building an application with this code.

I am stuck here to find any error in my code.

```
window.jQuery(document).ready(function(){
scriptposition('#deneme','Scr-Top-Center');
});
```

function scriptposition(valID, valPos){

```
var w = $(window).width();
var h = window.jQuery(window).height();
var dw = window.jQuery(document).width();
var dh = window.jQuery(document).height();
var objectw = window.jQuery(valID).width();
var objecth = window.jQuery(valID).height();

If (valPos=='Scr-Top-Center'){
var dleft = ((w/2) - (objectw/2));
    $(valID).css({top: 0, left:dleft, position:'absolute'});
}
If (valPos =='Scr-Left-Center'){
var dtop = ((h/2) - (objecth/2));
    $(valID).css({top: dtop, left:0, position:'absolute'});
}
If (valPos =='Scr-Right-Center'){
var dtop = ((h/2) - (objecth/2));
var dleft = (w) - (objectw);
    $(valID).css({top: dtop, left:dleft, position:'absolute'});
}
If (valPos =='Scr-Bottom-Center'){
var dtop = (h) - (objecth);
var dleft = (w/2) - (objectw/2);
    $(valID).css({top:dtop, left:dleft, position:'absolute'});
}
If (valPos =='Scr-Top-Left'){
    $(valID).css({top: 0, left:0, position:'absolute'});
}
If (valPos =='Scr-Top-Right'){
var dleft = (w) - (objectw);
    $(valID).css({top: 0, left:dleft, position:'absolute'});
}
If (valPos =='Scr-Bottom-Left'){
var dtop = (h) - (objecth);
    $(valID).css({top: dtop, left:0, position:'absolute'});
}
If (valPos =='Scr-Bottom-Right'){
var dtop = (h) - (objecth);
var dleft = (w) - (objectw);
    $(valID).css({top:dtop , left:dleft, position:'absolute'});
}
If (valPos =='Scr-Middle-Center'){
var dtop = (h/2) - (objecth/2);
var dleft = (w/2) - (objectw/2);
    $(valID).css({top:dtop , left:dleft, position:'absolute'});
}
If (valPos =='Scr-Middle-Left'){
var dtop = (h/2) - (objecth/2);
    $(valID).css({top:dtop, left:0, position:'absolute'});
}
If (valPos =='Scr-Middle-Right'){
var dtop = (h/2) - (objecth/2);
var dleft = (w) - (objectw);
    $(valID).css({top:dtop , left:dleft, position:'absolute'});
}
If (valPos =='Doc-Top-Center'){
var dleft = ((dw/2) - (objectw/2));
alert(dleft);
    $(valID).css({top: 0, left:dleft, position:'absolute'});
}
If (valPos =='Doc-Left-Center'){
var dtop = ((dh/2) - (objecth/2));
    $(valID).css({top: dtop, left:0, position:'absolute'});
}
If (valPos =='Doc-Right-Center'){
var dtop = ((dh/2) - (objecth/2));
var dleft = (dw) - (objectw);
    $(valID).css({top: dtop, left:dleft, position:'absolute'});
}
If (valPos =='Doc-Bottom-Center'){
var dtop = (dh) - (objecth);
var dleft = (dw/2) - (objectw/2);
    $(valID).css({top:dtop, left:dleft, position:'absolute'});
}
If (valPos =='Doc-Top-Left'){
    $(valID).css({top: 0, left:0, position:'absolute'});
}
If (valPos =='Doc-Top-Right'){
dleft = (dw) - (objectw);
    $(valID).css({top: 0, left:dleft, position:'absolute'});
}
If (valPos =='Doc-Bottom-Left'){
dtop = (dh) - (objecth);
    $(valID).css({top: dtop, left:0, position:'absolute'});
}
If (valPos =='Doc-Bottom-Right'){
dtop = (dh) - (objecth);
dleft = (dw) - (objectw);
    $(valID).css({top: dtop, left:dleft, position:'absolute'});
}
If (valPos =='Doc-Middle-Center'){
dtop = (dh/2) - (objecth/2);
dleft = (dw/2) - (objectw/2);
    $(valID).css({top: dtop, left:dleft, position:'absolute'});
}
If (valPos =='Doc-Middle-Left'){
dtop = (dh/2) - (objecth/2);
    $(valID).css({top: dtop, left:0, position:'absolute'});
}
If (valPos =='Doc-Middle-Right'){
dtop = (dh/2) - (objecth/2);
dleft = (dw/2) - (objectw/2);
    $(valID).css({top: dtop, left:dleft, position:'absolute'});
}
}
```

`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27555368/javascript-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token)

Answer (score 0):

You are using `If` instead of the correct `if`. That's the cause.
Consider using a plugin that helps with coding standards, such as [prettier](https://github.com/prettier/prettier). It helps in generating standardized code.

Here's your refactored code:

```
function scriptposition(valID, valPos) {
  var w = $(window).width();
  var h = window.jQuery(window).height();
  var dw = window.jQuery(document).width();
  var dh = window.jQuery(document).height();
  var objectw = window.jQuery(valID).width();
  var objecth = window.jQuery(valID).height();

  if (valPos == 'Scr-Top-Center') {
    var dleft = w / 2 - objectw / 2;
    $(valID).css({ top: 0, left: dleft, position: 'absolute' });
  }
  if (valPos == 'Scr-Left-Center') {
    var dtop = h / 2 - objecth / 2;
    $(valID).css({ top: dtop, left: 0, position: 'absolute' });
  }
  if (valPos == 'Scr-Right-Center') {
    var dtop = h / 2 - objecth / 2;
    var dleft = w - objectw;
    $(valID).css({ top: dtop, left: dleft, position: 'absolute' });
  }
  if (valPos == 'Scr-Bottom-Center') {
    var dtop = h - objecth;
    var dleft = w / 2 - objectw / 2;
    $(valID).css({ top: dtop, left: dleft, position: 'absolute' });
  }
  if (valPos == 'Scr-Top-Left') {
    $(valID).css({ top: 0, left: 0, position: 'absolute' });
  }
  if (valPos == 'Scr-Top-Right') {
    var dleft = w - objectw;
    $(valID).css({ top: 0, left: dleft, position: 'absolute' });
  }
  if (valPos == 'Scr-Bottom-Left') {
    var dtop = h - objecth;
    $(valID).css({ top: dtop, left: 0, position: 'absolute' });
  }
  if (valPos == 'Scr-Bottom-Right') {
    var dtop = h - objecth;
    var dleft = w - objectw;
    $(valID).css({ top: dtop, left: dleft, position: 'absolute' });
  }
  if (valPos == 'Scr-Middle-Center') {
    var dtop = h / 2 - objecth / 2;
    var dleft = w / 2 - objectw / 2;
    $(valID).css({ top: dtop, left: dleft, position: 'absolute' });
  }
  if (valPos == 'Scr-Middle-Left') {
    var dtop = h / 2 - objecth / 2;
    $(valID).css({ top: dtop, left: 0, position: 'absolute' });
  }
  if (valPos == 'Scr-Middle-Right') {
    var dtop = h / 2 - objecth / 2;
    var dleft = w - objectw;
    $(valID).css({ top: dtop, left: dleft, position: 'absolute' });
  }
  if (valPos == 'Doc-Top-Center') {
    var dleft = dw / 2 - objectw / 2;
    alert(dleft);
    $(valID).css({ top: 0, left: dleft, position: 'absolute' });
  }
  if (valPos == 'Doc-Left-Center') {
    var dtop = dh / 2 - objecth / 2;
    $(valID).css({ top: dtop, left: 0, position: 'absolute' });
  }
  if (valPos == 'Doc-Right-Center') {
    var dtop = dh / 2 - objecth / 2;
    var dleft = dw - objectw;
    $(valID).css({ top: dtop, left: dleft, position: 'absolute' });
  }
  if (valPos == 'Doc-Bottom-Center') {
    var dtop = dh - objecth;
    var dleft = dw / 2 - objectw / 2;
    $(valID).css({ top: dtop, left: dleft, position: 'absolute' });
  }
  if (valPos == 'Doc-Top-Left') {
    $(valID).css({ top: 0, left: 0, position: 'absolute' });
  }
  if (valPos == 'Doc-Top-Right') {
    dleft = dw - objectw;
    $(valID).css({ top: 0, left: dleft, position: 'absolute' });
  }
  if (valPos == 'Doc-Bottom-Left') {
    dtop = dh - objecth;
    $(valID).css({ top: dtop, left: 0, position: 'absolute' });
  }
  if (valPos == 'Doc-Bottom-Right') {
    dtop = dh - objecth;
    dleft = dw - objectw;
    $(valID).css({ top: dtop, left: dleft, position: 'absolute' });
  }
  if (valPos == 'Doc-Middle-Center') {
    dtop = dh / 2 - objecth / 2;
    dleft = dw / 2 - objectw / 2;
    $(valID).css({ top: dtop, left: dleft, position: 'absolute' });
  }
  if (valPos == 'Doc-Middle-Left') {
    dtop = dh / 2 - objecth / 2;
    $(valID).css({ top: dtop, left: 0, position: 'absolute' });
  }
  if (valPos == 'Doc-Middle-Right') {
    dtop = dh / 2 - objecth / 2;
    dleft = dw / 2 - objectw / 2;
    $(valID).css({ top: dtop, left: dleft, position: 'absolute' });
  }
}
```

Comment: You should also consider using a `switch ... case` instead of all those `if` conditionals.